# How to enable debugging messages in Juno (Julia editor)

Tags: debugging, julia, juno-ide

The [Julia docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Logging/index.html#Environment-variables-1) are pretty clear on how to enable debugging messages from `@debug` macros, i.e. run `export JULIA_DEBUG=mymodule` or `export JULIA_DEBUG=all` on the command line before starting Julia. However, is there an easy way to enable debugging from within the Juno, or, more generally, while Julia is running?

I tried fiddling with `Base.CoreLogging.disable_logging` , `Base.CoreLogging.BelowMinLevel` and `Base.CoreLogging._min_enabled_level` without success.

I know I can set env variables for Julia in the Juno settings. But that's kind of annoying to work with as it requires restarting Julia. I really want to have the following workflow while working interactively:

1. Enter a line in the REPL
2. Stumble upon a bug from your own code that you didn't see coming.
3. Enable debugging.
4. Run that line again.
5. See the debug logs.
6. Fix your code.
7. Disable debug logging again.

Which I think is nicer than the common practice of commenting and un-commenting `printf` everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable `@debug` everywhere (this will only affect code loaded *after* running the following expression):

```
julia>ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"] = "all"
```

Enable `@debug` in file `foo.jl` (according to docs, haven't tested this):

```
julia>ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"] = "foo"
```

Disable `@debug`:

```
ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"] = ""
```

**important note**: macros are evaluated when code is loaded. So the tricks above will only have effect on code that is loaded *after* changing the value of `JULIA_DEBUG`. So after setting it to e.g. `all`, nothing will have changed. Reload the modules you want to `@debug`.

Answer (score 0):

To enable @debug messages logging in your julia script:

```
# ... script ...

ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"]="all"

# debug messages are now enabled.
# ... Rest of the script...
```

The addition of `ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"]="all"` will enable @debug messages when running the script in Juno or running it with `Julia` from your terminal.